# How to use if condition in view by Model relation. Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I just want to foreach `{{ choice_question_number }}` by only `where('user_id',Auth::id());`.

> In view how to check that user_id, or how to check in controller by using user_id. I'm taking questions by using Question model thats the problem.

**View**

```
@foreach ($duplicate->topic->choices as $choice)
    {{ $choice->question_number }}
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
$duplicates = Question::selectRaw("count('id') as total, topic_id")->with('topic', 'topic.choices')->groupBy('topic_id')->get();
return view('choices.index',compact('too','duplicates'));
```

**Model**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'time',
    'topic_id',
    'question_number'
];

public function topic(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic');
}
```

Comment: While you could do this in the view by filtering the collection, it's probably better to just load the correct relationship items to begin with.